# Why aren't bookmarklets working in chrome when site is down?

Tags: bookmarklet

I was trying to create a simple bookmarklet on chrome for browsing to isup.me and checking if the site is really down (javascript:window.open('http://isup.me/'+document.location.href)). 
It works well, except for when when I actually need it, because apparently bookmarklets won't work on a site if it wasn't loaded...

Any way to go around this? (and why is it working this way?)